# Cannot connect to a SVN repository using Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

We have installed CollabNet Subversion Edge on a Windows 2008 R2 Standard server that is also runnning IIS 7.0.  All of the Subversion traffic has been configured to use an SSL connection over port 8080.

The URL to our repository use the following structure

> https://servername.domain:8080/svn/repositoryname

Certain employees in our company cannot connection to the URL using Tortoise SVN and Visual Studio Ankh.  They can connect to the URL using Internet Explorer

Is there a way to monitor port 8080 to see if there is another application conflicting with the Subversion traffic to prevent them from connecting through Tortoise and Ankh?

(Not sure if this is Stack Overflow or Server Fault question.  I will start with Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Verified that it is not proxy settings.  We narrowed it down to the settings on the workstation.

Comment: can you access with svn command client on this particular workstation? what is the error msg?

Comment: @PeterParker - Do I need to install SVN Slik on the workstation to access Subversion via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that is was a VPN client that was preventing our developers from connecting to the SVN repository over port 8080.

We needed to disable/uninstall the VPN software in order to use the SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion Edge will not be able to start the Apache server if there is another application using that port.  You will also see an error on the top of the console that it could not bind to the port.

On the Administration tab of Subversion Edge you will see "Server Logs".  Look at the logs named "access_YYYY_MM_DD.log".  These are the Apache access logs.  If the client request is reaching the Apache server it will be logged here.

Other than that, I would say you need to share the error message the user receives.  I would also try a few things like intentionally misspelling the hostname and changing to a port number that is not used so you can see how the error message changes (or does not change) as you introduce those options.

For example (this is with latest 1.7 release candidate and messages are a little different):

$ svn ls http://foo/svn/repos

svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://foo/svn/repos': Could not resolve hostname `foo': Host not found (http://foo)

$ svn ls http://cu171.cloud.sp.collab.net:8888/svn/repos

svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://cu171.cloud.sp.collab.net:8888/svn/repos'

svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://cu171.cloud.sp.collab.net:8888/svn/repos': could not connect to server (http://cu171.cloud.sp.collab.net:8888)

Comment: I checked the access logs and see 408 HTTP errors from the workstation IP address that is having issues